# Is there a castable material similar to high-density EVA foam?

Tags: foam

I tried a few Polytek 2-part mixtures to make expanded PU foams in the density range of 8LB per cuft. These are still too soft as I am trying to achieve the firmness and surface feel of a yoga block (mostly made of high density EVA foam). Can anyone suggest any suitable material?

Just a note that EVA foam is easily gouged damaged while PU is not.